# Shortcut for VCS » Git » Commit File

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, phpstorm

Is there a way to assign a keyboard shortcut to *VCS* » *Git* » *Commit File...* . The entry doesn't seem to be available in *Keymap*.

In PhpStorm 7 that is.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Please look for "Check in" in the KeyMap. 
There is an open issue for this naming problem: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-50642

Comment: Same applies if you want to assign a keyboard shortcut to 'VCS > Subversion > Commit File'. Look for 'Check In' in keymap.